# Dealing with deprecated methods in android

Tags: java, android, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I'm currently building an app targeting API 23, with a minimum API of 19.
In API 23 some of the methods of the android.widget.TimePicker component was replaced.

For example:

```
TimePicker.getCurrentHour();
```

was replaced by:

```
TimePicker.getHour();
```

Now, when using TimePicker in my app I should check whether the device is using API 22 or above with the following if statement:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        TimePicker.getHour();
    else
        TimePicker.getCurrentHour();
```

What I did was extending the TimePicker class and implementing the deprecated methods like this:

```
public class TimePicker extends android.widget.TimePicker {

    public TimePicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setCurrentHour(int hour) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            super.setHour(hour);
        else
            super.setCurrentHour(hour);
    }

    public void setCurrentMinute(int minute) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            super.setMinute(minute);
        else
            super.setCurrentMinute(minute);
    }

    public int getCurrentHour() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            return super.getHour();
        else
            return super.getCurrentHour();
    }

    public int getCurrentMinute() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            return super.getMinute();
        else
            return super.getCurrentMinute();
    }
}
```

so the user who uses this class won't affect the change of the methods (he should only replace the import of the TimePicker class in his implementation).

Is it the right way doing so? or there is a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: It's a good way. In my opinion, you nailed it! :) Perhaps your methods should be named after the new name convention, making the transition easier when you drop support for pre M.

Comment: hey, What this .M is about ?

Comment: Build.VERSION_CODES.M is refers to API 23 (Android Marshmallow)

Comment: I keep all of my methods that require a version check in a separate class (SDKHelper) so that they are all in one place should the requirements change in the future and the app code is not littered with checks through all various classes.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 5):

The way you performed is good practice as far as I can read from the shown part.

However, as I have seen so far, the best practice has been to make different subdivisions from each class you intend to publish, and stack the program during installation.

This basically means that `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)` goes at the top of the class.

If your project intends to go under more versions, I suggest this:

```
public class Example extends moreExamples implements additionalExamples{
   switch(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT){
      case Build.VERSION_CODES.M:
         codeVersionM();
         break;
      case Build.VERSION_CODES.L:
         codeVersionL();
         break;
      case Build.VERSION_CODES.K:
         codeVersionK();
         break;
      default:
         errorNoBuildImplemented();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you did is okay but probably not the best solution because:

- You are using the old method names instead of the new ones
- Creating a custom class forces you to use that custom class in your layouts and code in replacement of the framework's class. It's preferred to avoid creating custom views if you can.

There are generally 2 recommended ways:

1) Keep using the deprecated method until you upgrade your minSDK. It will call the new method internally in the new implementation:

```
@Deprecated
public void setCurrentHour(@NonNull Integer currentHour) {
    setHour(currentHour);
}
```

2) Create a static helper class that will call the correct method according to the SDK version. That's what the support library does for many classes already ([`TextViewCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompat.html), [`ViewCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html), ...):

```
public class TimePickerCompat {

    public static void setHour(TimePicker timePicker, int hour) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            timePicker.setHour(hour);
        } else {
            timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the *new* method names. That way you can eventually get rid of your compatibility class when you raise your min sdk version to 23, without having to change any code other than your imports.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class TimePicker extends android.widget.TimePicker
{
    public TimePicker(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public TimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public TimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public void setHour(int hour)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            super.setHour(hour);
        else
            super.setCurrentHour(hour);
    }

    public void setMinute(int minute)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            super.setMinute(minute);
        else
            super.setCurrentMinute(minute);
    }

    public int getHour()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            return super.getHour();
        else
            return super.getCurrentHour();
    }

    public int getMinute()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            return super.getMinute();
        else
            return super.getCurrentMinute();
    }
}
```